# how to Parse Json Object and get Data in android

Tags: java, android

```
   SoapObject data=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
                String result = String.valueOf(((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn).getProperty(0));

                JSONObject _jobjec = new JSONObject(result);
                UserId = _jobjec.get("UserId").toString();
                UserParentId = _jobjec.get("UserParentId").toString();
                UserName = _jobjec.get("UserName").toString();
                UserPassword = _jobjec.get("UserPassword").toString();
                UserMobile = _jobjec.get("UserMobile").toString();
                UserEmail = _jobjec.get("UserEmail").toString();
                UserMpin = _jobjec.get("UserMpin").toString();
```

This is my COde i am trying to JOSon Parse and get value but what happen { ,} remove  in result when i make json Object and trying and get value then i get Excepion i am getting 
String.valueOf(((SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn).getProperty(0) :

```
{"UserId":"2","UserParentId":"1","UserName":"Anilkumar","UserPassword":"12546",
"UserMobile":"8130513899","UserEmail":"anilaat87@gmail.com","UserMpin":"7890",
"UserBalance":"20.0000","UserResponseMessage":"Is Valid"}
```

but unable to parse it

Comment: Comma is not your problem, please share your error code

Comment: post the exception stacktrace.

Comment: {"UserId":"2","UserParentId":"1","UserName":"Anilkumar","UserPassword":"12546","UserMobile":"8130513899","UserEmail":"anilaat87@gmail.com","UserMpin":"7890","UserBalance":"20.0000","UserResponseMessage":"Is Valid"} this i am getting   here  JSONObject _jobjec = new JSONObject("{"+result); but unable to parse

Answer (score 0):

Directly using JSONObject to parse POJO is tedious and error prone, recommended using one of the below libraries:

- [GSON](https://github.com/google/gson)
- [JACKSON](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
- [MOSHI](https://github.com/square/moshi)
- [JSON.simple](https://github.com/fangyidong/json-simple)

First, define your [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class, you can use some online service, e.g. [this one](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) or [this](http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com/),

Just paste your example json string, then you can get below pojo class (you don't need to write it on your own) in 2 seconds:

```
package com.example;

import javax.annotation.Generated;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;


public class Example {

    @SerializedName("UserId")
    @Expose
    public String userId;
    @SerializedName("UserParentId")
    @Expose
    public String userParentId;
    @SerializedName("UserName")
    @Expose
    public String userName;
    @SerializedName("UserPassword")
    @Expose
    public String userPassword;
    @SerializedName("UserMobile")
    @Expose
    public String userMobile;
    @SerializedName("UserEmail")
    @Expose
    public String userEmail;
    @SerializedName("UserMpin")
    @Expose
    public String userMpin;
    @SerializedName("UserBalance")
    @Expose
    public String userBalance;
    @SerializedName("UserResponseMessage")
    @Expose
    public String userResponseMessage;

}
```

Then to get the java object, use below [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) calls:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
Example instance = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Example.class);
```

If you use Jackson or other libraries, the same process applies, and they differ only in the detailed function calls.

Answer (score 0):

> you have to write code like this

```
           SoapObject data=(SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
            String result = String.valueOf(((SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn).getProperty(0));

            JSONObject _jobjec = new JSONObject(result);
            UserId = _jobjec.getString("UserId");
            UserParentId = _jobjec.getString("UserParentId");
            UserName = _jobjec.getString("UserName");
            UserPassword = _jobjec.getString("UserPassword");
            UserMobile = _jobjec.getString("UserMobile");
            UserEmail = _jobjec.getString("UserEmail");
            UserMpin = _jobjec.getString("UserMpin");
```

Comment: i have written same like this but still i am getting Exception

Comment: org.json.JSONException: Names must be strings, this exception am getting

Comment: i hope to you take String for UserId, UserParentId, UserName, UserPassword, UserPassword, UserPassword, UserEmail,UserMobile etc.